# Modular arithmetics problem

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime integer, and let $m,k \in \mathbb{N}$. If $m \equiv k$ (mod $(p-1)$), show that:

1. $u^k \equiv u^m$ (mod $p$), $\forall u \in \mathbb{Z}$
2. If $u \equiv v$ (mod $p$), then $u^k \equiv v^m$ (mod $p$), $\forall u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$

Couldn't find anything related with this. The only thing related with $(p-1)$ I found was Wilson's Theorem, but I can't see any relation with that question. Can anyone show how can I start to solve that? Thanks.

Comment: See [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: [Deja vu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4124430/modular-exponentiation-and-primes)

Comment: Sorry, that is a rep and I didn't knew. I'll Close the question.

Comment: Apply **mod order reduction** as described in the linked dupe, using Fermat's little Theorem, and the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)